# How can I stop jmeter test to fail until While controller gives the required result

Tags: jmeter

I have a request that uploads an image.

Then I have another request that gets the above image and shows uploadStatus=published. For the first 20-30 secs the request will fail and will give error "404" with "No asset found". After some time, it will show the uploadStatus=published in the response and then this request will pass. How can I make sure the test doesn't fail until it waits for e.g. 1 min or until it finds 'uploadStatus=published'. As I see the jmeter report, I can see this request failed for 97% times and then it passed. Any help would be appreciated on how can I tackle this in while controller or whatever?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the failure in the While Controller using [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter) and ticking `Ignore Status` box there:

[image]

this way it will mark the Sampler as passed even despite [HTTP Status Code 404](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404)

[image]

with regards to 1 minute - you can add another condition into the function you're using in the While Controller, example [__groovy function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) condition:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('variable-holding-the-uploadstatus-here') != 'Published'  && System.currentTimeMillis() - (vars.get('TESTSTART.MS') as long) < 60000,)}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this .I have added the response assertion and it is now ignoring "Asset not found" but when it finds "uploadStatus=Published" in the last request then it failed and giving error because it didn't find "No Assets found!":

Assertion failure message:Test failed: text expected to contain /No Assets found!/

Comment: You can give 2 conditions with OR clause

Comment: Great, thanks. Just one last thing regarding adding 60sec in while controller. How can I make it fail if I don't get "status=Published" after 60secs? It is currently stopping the test with last request passed.

Comment: Either copy the request and paste it after the While Controller or if you prefer to respect the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) you can move the request under a [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and reference it twice using [Module Controllers](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) inside and outside the While Controller.